# nginx configuration for subdomain and proxy server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, subdomain, node.js

I was trying a lot of other post solutions here and no one can help me to solve my problem. I have a simple nginx configuration with https and a node.js app with the main path `/` and for a subdomain another path `/api`. I can access to `mywebapp.com` correctly, but if I try to access to `api.mywebapp.com` it redirects me to the "Welcome to nginx" page. I have the DNS record `api.mywebapp.com` pointing to my server ip address.

This is my nginx config blocks:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name mywebapp.com;

    # SSL
    include /etc/letsencrypt/mycerts.conf;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name api.mywebapp.com;

    # SSL 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/mycerts.conf;      
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location /api {
        limit_req zone=mylimit;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Does it actually redirect you, or does it just show the welcome page? Are you actually trying to reach api.mywebapp.com via https? The output of `wget --spider -S https://api.mywebapp.com` could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configured your proxy for

```
location /api {
  # ...
}
```

So it is only reachable with `https://api.mywebapp.com/api/`.

You most probably want to change this to

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api;  # <- keep this
  # ...
}
```